# Python programs suddenly get killed

Tags: python, ram, out-of-memory, memory-leaks

I'm running some python programs that are quite heavy. I've been running this script for several weeks now, but in the past couple of days, the program gets killed with the message:

```
Killed
```

I tried [creating a new swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075505/how-do-i-increase-swapfile-in-ubuntu-18-04) with 8 GB, but it kept happening.

I also tried using:

```
dmesg -T| grep -E -i -B100 'killed process'
```

which listed out the error:

```
[Sat Oct 17 02:08:41 2020] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service,task=python,pid=56849,uid=1000
[Sat Oct 17 02:08:41 2020] Out of memory: Killed process 56849 (python) total-vm:21719376kB, anon-rss:14311012kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:4kB, UID:1000 pgtables:40572kB oom_score_adj:0
```

I have a strong machine and I tried also not running anything else when running ( Pycharm or terminal) but it keeps happening.

specs:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (64bit)
- 15.4 GiB RAM
- Intel Core i7-105100 CPU @ 1.80 GHz x 8

when running `free -h t`

```
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       2.4Gi        10Gi       313Mi       2.0Gi        12Gi
Swap:         8.0Gi       1.0Gi       7.0Gi
```

Comment: How exactly did you create the swap file? Did you also activate it?  Please [edit] your question and add the exact commands you ran. Also show us the output of `free -h` that indicates the swapfile is in use.

Comment: You need to check the output of `free` while your python script is running. You will see that it is using all of the available RAM and also the swap. If so, all you can do is fic the script or give it more ram/swap.

Answer (score 20):

There's nothing to be done here, I'm afraid. The process is being killed by the OOM killer (Out Of Memory Killer), which is a process of the operating system whose job it is to kill jobs that are taking up too much memory before they crash your machine. This is a good thing. Without it, your machine would simply become unresponsive.

So, you need to figure out why your python script is taking up so much memory, and try to make it so that it uses less.

The only other alternative is to try and get more swap, or more RAM of course, but that feels like a bandaid. If this is your python script, you should focus on making it less memory hungry if at all possible.

Answer (score 5):

May be buffer memory got increased since you are running the program for more days. You can clean the buffer memory using the below garbage collection function. Also, you can add gc.collect() wherever required.

```
 import gc

 gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue. I have a python script which runs for a few minutes creating matplotlib plot files. If i run the script from the commandline directly via python script.py then everything work fine. As soon as i run this from a bash script, the memory usage increases over time an finaly stops with the same kill message from above. I haven't yet found a solution but i hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

- It can be insufficient memory issue
- To find out it, you can use journalctl command

  - jounalctl --since "1 hour ago"|grep killed
  - jounalctl --since "1 hour ago"
  - in anyway, just find out what are in logs when the script was got killed
- If it is a insufficient memory issue then,

  - if any possible improvement in the code, then do it
  - if no, then try to increase swap space if there is not enough swap space

    - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066358/increasing-the-swap-space-on-ubuntu

Comment: `journalctl --since "10 min ago"|grep killed`

Answer (score 0):

I read about how Instagram developers [disabled Garbage collection altogether](https://instagram-engineering.com/dismissing-python-garbage-collection-at-instagram-4dca40b29172).

The reason was when processes create child process, they share the memory but as the memory page change, new are copied and thus increasing RAM usage.

So disabling the garbage collection to not store generations before removing the memory would help in decreasing RAM usage. As gc is not actually disabled when ref count reaches zero but it just not have threshold to wait until it is reached.

This can be done by setting threshold to `0`.

```
import gc
gc.set_threshold(0)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).